# How to optimise Django FormView for database performance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have never optimised my Django code and I'm not sure I fully understand [Django optimisation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/#database-access-optimization) so can you tell me if this FormView class can be somehow optimised (I'm guessing yes ...)?

The part of code which I'm worried about is the Patient lookup: `Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])` - it's happening 3 times ... Does it mean **Django will hit the database 3 times or only once?**

Can/should this be optimised, and if yes - how?

```
class PatientNotes(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):

    slug_url_kwarg = 'patientId'
    slug_field = 'patientId'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'patientId'

    template_name = "patient/patient_detail.html"
    form_class = AddNewNoteForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PatientNotes, self).get_queryset()
        self.current_patient = Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])
        my_result = queryset.filter(patient=self.current_patient)
        return my_result

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.patient = Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])
        self.object.note_created_by_date = datetime.date.today()
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('PatientDetailView', kwargs={'patientId': self.object.patient.patientId})
```

Comment: use profiling tools (e.g. `Pycharm` IDE have a profiling tools) or using this link: https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Answer (score 0):

It means that your view contains duplicated queries that will hit the database multiple times.

Using

```
class PatientNotes(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        # This will hit the database to fetch patient object.
        self.current_patient = Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # This will also hit the database to fetch patient object.
        self.object = Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])
        ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        # This will also hit the database to fetch patient object.
        self.object.patient = Patient.objects.get(patientId=self.kwargs['patientId'])
        ...
```

This is considered duplicated queries made during a single request.

To fix this consider updating the `get` and `post` methods setting the current object to `None` for a `get` request in cases of FormView that don't required updating the existing object the `post` method would set the current object after saving the form.

I would recommend using [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) or [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) since your trying to set the `self.object` i.e the current object since [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) are for processing forms i.e only validating and saving the form data.

Model field shouldn't be camel cased `Patient.patientId` should be `Patient.patient_id` they should be lower cased separated by underscores.

```
class PatientNotes(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    model = Patient
    slug_url_kwarg = 'patient_id'
    slug_field = 'patient_id'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'patient_id'
    template_name = 'patient/patient_detail.html'
    form_class = AddNewNoteForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patient_object = self.get_object()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.patient_object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.patient = self.patient_object
        self.object.note_created_by_date = datetime.date.today()
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # view names should be lower cased separated by underscores.
        return reverse('patient_detail_view', kwargs={'patient_id': self.patient_object.patient_id})
```